# Is it possible to pass parameters to a .dtsx package on the command line?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, dtexec

I am currently executing an SSIS package (package.dtsx) from the command line using `Dtexec`.
This is as simple as:

```
dtexec /f Package.dtsx
```

However, I have some parameters that I would like to pass to the package for it to use during execution. The documentation implies that this might be possible (i.e. the /Par parameter), but it is not clear.
Is it possible to pass parameters to a `.DTSX` file using `dtexec`?

Comment: Whats not clear? did you try it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Of course yes, you can assign values to variables using dtexec**

*Syntax*

```
dtexec /f mypackage.dtsx /set \package.variables[myvariable].Value;myvalue
```

*Example*

```
dtexec.exe /FILE "D:\TestPkg.dtsx" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::Name].Properties[Value];"LOAD_DAILY" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::File].Properties[Value];"D:\Load Test.txt" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::Count].Properties[Value];5
```

**References**

- [dtexec Utility (SSIS Tool)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [DTEXEC package with multiple parameters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8be2d7e1-8d65-4d8c-8710-70ea06c91f7f/dtexec-package-with-multiple-parameters?forum=winserverpowershell)