# How does a variable like `User::filePath` get passed to a script in an SSIS package that's run by an SQL Agent Job?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-agent-job

If I look directly at the script, the call to sp_add_jobstep when using `CREATE SCRIPT` for this is:

```
@command=N'/FILE "<local-server-path-to.dtsx-file>" /CONNECTION "FlatFileConnection;"<unc-path-to.csv-file>" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E'
```

So it seems to me that the `<unc-path-to.csv-file>` somehow specifies the value of `User::filePath` or maybe the `FlatFileConnection` within the SSIS package.

The Job Step Properties for the SQL Agent job (in the UI) under `General` and then the `Command line` tab, have the `Restore the original options` selected, so where does the `User::filePath` get specified?

Comment: check the following links 1- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48511517/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-to-a-dtsx-package-on-the-command-line 2- https://socalsql.com/2010/08/30/passing-parameters-into-ssis-from-a-sql-job/

Comment: "somehow specifies the value of User::filePath" No it doesn't it just sets some properties on a connection manager. You might have some logic in your package that in turn sets the value of `User::filePath` but we don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code:

```
@command=N'/FILE "<local-server-path-to.dtsx-file>" /CONNECTION "FlatFileConnection;"<unc-path-to.csv-file>" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E'
```

is the arguments passed to the dtexec utility which is the used to execute SSIS packages.

You can simply pass the `[User::FilePath]` value using the following line of code:

```
/SET \Package.Variables[User::FilePath].Properties[Value];"C:\File.dtsx"
```

The whole command will be:

```
@command=N'/FILE "<local-server-path-to.dtsx-file>" /CONNECTION "FlatFileConnection;"<unc-path-to.csv-file>" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E /SET \Package.Variables[User::FilePath].Properties[Value];"C:\File.dtsx"'
```

Referring to the [dtexec Utility documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms162810(v=sql.105)):

> /Set Overrides the configuration of a variable, property, container, log provider, Foreach enumerator, or connection within a package. When this option is used, /Set changes the propertyPath argument to the value specified. Multiple /Set options can be specified.
>
> The following is an example of executing a package and providing a new value for a variable:
>
> `dtexec /f mypackage.dtsx /set \package.variables[myvariable].Value;myvalue`